# Вопрос по git и netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, github, git-push

Работаю в netbeans.

Создал на локальном компе ветку мастер.

Потом зарегистрировался на github и через тот же netbeans отправил на него свой проект

В итоге в самом netbeans пишется 1 локальная ветка, 1 удаленная ветка и того 2 ветки.

Теперь когда я меняю проект я нажимаю  Добавить(`add`) и Фиксация (`commit`) и все сохранияется на локалке, а вот чтобы на github тоже все поменялось какая то хренатень, нужно еще нажимать на кнопку Удаленный - Вытолкнуть(`push`).

Я вообще все правильно понял, что ветки должно быть 2? и правильно ли все делаю?
И правильно что push нужен для удаленного сервера?
Ведь судя по тому что я написал на локалке `push` вообще не используется.

Comment: в этом то и вся прелесть git, что многое можно делать локально. Некоторые локальные ветки могут "связываться" с удаленными (те, которые на github). Обычно их имена совпадают.

"выталкивать" не объязательно после каждого коммита. Более того, можно себе комитить часто, а потом оформить это одним коммитом и отправить на удаленный сервер.

Answer (score 1):

Читайте http://git-scm.com/book или на русском - http://git-scm.com/book/ru

Кратко отвечая на ваш вопрос, скажу, что вы все делаете правильно. Любой коммит происходит в  локальную ветвь. Чтобы изменения попали в удаленный репозиторий, нужно выполнить команду push, чтобы получить изменения из удаленного репозитория, нужно выполнить команду pull.